# Getting "Invalid parameter number" when updating database, why?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make my CMS be able to edit different fields (e.g. name). When I hit "Update", though, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME10/1/b5035381/public_html/affinity/cms/process/editRecord.php: in /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME10/1/b5035381/public_html/affinity/cms/process/editRecord.php on line 28 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME10/1/b5035381/public_html/affinity/cms/process/editRecord.php on line 28 Call Stack: 0.0029 659144 1. {main}() /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME10/1/b5035381/public_html/affinity/cms/process/editRecord.php:0 0.0135 672928 2. PDOStatement->execute() /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME10/1/b5035381/public_html/affinity/cms/process/editRecord.php:28

Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// add your includes for connections and functions
// make sure the path is correct
require ('../../includes/conn.inc.php');
require ('../../includes/functions.inc.php');

// sanitize user variables
$splayerName = safeString($_POST['playerName']);
$splayerDescription = safeString($_POST['playerDescription']);
$splayerImage = safeString($_POST['playerImage']);
$splayerRank = safeString($_POST['playerRank']);
$splayerSpec = safeString($_POST['playerSpec']);
$splayerID = safeInt($_POST['playerID']);

// build prepare statement
$sql = "UPDATE affinity SET playerName = :playerName,
playerDescription = :playerDescription,
playerImage = :playerImage,
playerRank = :playerRank,
playerSpec = :playerSpec
WHERE playerID = :playerID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':playerName', $splayerName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerDescription', $splayerDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerImage', $splayerImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerRank', $splayerRank, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerRank', $splayerRank, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerSpec', $splayerSpec, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

// redirect browser
header("Location: ../cms.php");

// make sure no other code executed
exit;
?>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working; how can I fix it?

Comment: you are binding 5 variables but use 6 fields. You have rank double

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's your bind for playerID? That's whats causing it. You'e binding Rank twice and ID never, and they should be in order correct?

```
$stmt->bindParam(':playerName', $splayerName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerDescription', $splayerDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerImage', $splayerImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerRank', $splayerRank, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerSpec', $splayerSpec, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerID', $splayerID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

> :playerRank

has been bound 2 times and

> :playerID

Haven't been bound.

And :

> :playerSpec

Should be bound as a string, not an int.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':playerName', $splayerName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerDescription', $splayerDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerImage', $splayerImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerRank', $splayerRank, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerSpec', $splayerSpec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerID', $splayerID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// add your includes for connections and functions
// make sure the path is correct

require ('../../includes/conn.inc.php');

require ('../../includes/functions.inc.php');

// sanitize user variables

$splayerName = safeString($_POST['playerName']);
$splayerDescription = safeString($_POST['playerDescription']);
$splayerImage = safeString($_POST['playerImage']);
$splayerRank = safeString($_POST['playerRank']);
$splayerSpec = safeString($_POST['playerSpec']);
$splayerID = safeInt($_POST['playerID']);

// build prepare statement

$sql = "UPDATE affinity SET playerName = :playerName,
playerDescription = :playerDescription,
playerImage = :playerImage,
playerRank = :playerRank,
playerSpec = :playerSpec
WHERE playerID = :playerID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerName', $splayerName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerDescription', $splayerDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerImage', $splayerImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerRank', $splayerRank, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerSpec', $splayerSpec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':playerID', $splayerID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

// redirect browser

header("Location: ../cms.php");

// make sure no other code executed

exit;
?>
```